# Jogo em Java usando Random,Boolean,Scanner,while,if/else

Tags: java

A ideia do jogo é usar um random de 1 a 100 e o usuário acertar, quando o numero do usuário for maior, envio uma mensagem avisando o usuário, do mesmo jeito se for menor e dando mais chances para o usuário acertar.

O código em si não esta compilando e eu não estou achando o erro

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Random rand = new Random();
    int numeroSorte = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;

    System.out.println("Adivinhe o numero que estou pensando, ele esta entre 1 e 100");

    boolean continuar = true;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
    while (continuar) {

        System.out.print("digite um numero ");
        int numeroUsuario = Integer.valueOf(scan.next());

        if (numeroUsuario == numeroSorte) {
            System.out.println("Parabens Voce acertou o numero ! ^^ ");
            continuar = false;

        } else if (numeroUsuario < numeroSorte) {
            System.out.println("o numero " + numeroUsuario + "é menor que o meu numero");
        } else {
            System.out.println("o numero " + numeroUsuario + "é maior que o meu numero");
        }
    }
    scan.close();

}
}
```

Comment: Por favor, leia isso: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/28595

Comment: O proxy na rede aqui bloqueia fotos da maioria dos domínios de compartilhamento de foto, como imgur (usado pelo stack overflow), poste o código se não eu e muita gente não vamos conseguir ver nada. Outra coisa, procura escrever corretamente, O seu uso de `c` como sendo `se` me fez confundir duas vezes a leitura, não precisa ser um expert em português, mas evite abreviações desnecessárias.

Comment: Você não importou as classes necessárias. Também não está usando o operador `new` de maneira correta

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, eu corrigi o erro de usar a foto, nas próximas perguntas não vou usar foto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seria muito mais fácil eu pudesse copiar o código, alterar ele e colocar a versão corrigida nesta resposta, mas você postou o código como uma droga de uma imagem e portanto fica difícil.

O problema é que `random rand = newrandom();` deveria ser `Random rand = new Random();`. Preste atenção nas letras maiúsculas e no espaço.

Você também esqueceu os `import`s de `Random` e de `Scanner`.

Você também parece ter colocado a sua classe na pasta errada ou com uma declaração de pacote incorreta.

Use a instrução `break;` ao invés de uma variável `continuar`.

`scan.close();` não é algo que tenha sentido de se fazer.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, irei fazer isso, e arrumei o erro em questão da imagem e coloquei o código, e não irei mais cometer esse erro de usar a foto.